# Passing variables inside steps to html file in yaml

Tags: github-actions

Is it possible to assign a variable and pass it to an html that executes within the same step?

```
jobs:
Run_Test:          
    steps:       
      - name: Step one
        (...)
      - name: Step two
        if: always()
        uses:  dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3.6.0
        with:
          server_address: (...)
          server_port: (...)
          username: (...)
          password: (...)
          subject: ${{ github.job }} execution finished ${{ job.status }}
          body: |
            Executed by: ${{ github.actor}}
            Job name: ${{ github.job }}
            Repository: ${{ github.repository }}
            Status: ${{ job.status }}
          html_body: file:///some/route/to/file/main.html
          to: (...)
```

I need to display the variables inside the body in the html file in html_body

```
        <p>Executed by: ${{ github.actor}}</p>
        <p>Job name: ${{ github.job }}</p>
        <p>Repository: ${{ github.repository }}</p>
        <p>Status:${{ job.status }}</p>
```

Is this possible or is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file://` functionality is specific to `action-send-mail` and doesn't support variable substitution in the file, but you can of course just give the content directly:

```yaml
body: |
  Executed by: ${{ github.actor}}
  Job name: ${{ github.job }}
  Repository: ${{ github.repository }}
  Status: ${{ job.status }}
html_body: |
  <p>Executed by: ${{ github.actor}}</p>
  <p>Job name: ${{ github.job }}</p>
  <p>Repository: ${{ github.repository }}</p>
  <p>Status:${{ job.status }}</p>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, and would it be possible to enter the path of the .html file without using `file://`, or is it necessary to put all the html inside `html_body:`?

Comment: @OscarP This would only be possible if Github Actions offered functionality for it. It doesn't currently.